# View the Microsoft Store association after the UWP app being published

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

Is there a way that I can see the Package.StoreAssociation.xml after the UWP app published to a .appxbundle?

I used 7zip to look inside the .appxbundle but can't find the Package.StoreAssociation.xml. 
What I need is to see the associated app's Id to determine which app got associated. That information stored inside the Package.StoreAssociation.xml.

Comment: Hello, why do you need to unpack the application? If you need to view the relevant binding information of the application, you can view it in your own project or in the corresponding application in the partner center.

Comment: I have a single app but binding to different Microsoft Store associations. Since all are the same I just need to see which one I bonded. This is just for my reference.

Comment: Hello, do you mean that your single app project corresponds to multiple apps in the store? I am not sure if I understand what you mean. However, unpacking is not recommended, it may leak some developers' private data. You can choose to repackage after store association, and place the package according to the corresponding application folder.

Comment: Yes. The apps are hidden and can only accessed using the private url. What I’m asking is a one time thing. I mixed up few apps and now I have to find the bonded store app I’d. Can I do that by examining the package or not?

Comment: Hello, about the information you need, you need to unpack the `.appx` package in the `appxbundle` again, you can check the Manifest file to confirm the package name